# Expanding XSD complex element types with XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I've got an XSD document I'm trying to parse with XSL for documentation purposes where the complexTypes frequently contain elements that are other complexTypes.  I'd like to display the contents of these complex type elements next to their containers if possible.  Here's a simple example of what I'm working with:

```
<xs:complexType name="S">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="A" type="X"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="X">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="F"/>
    <xs:element name="G"/>
    <xs:element name="H"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

How would I get the above to show as something like:  "S contains A of type X(which contains F, G, and H)"?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Added example:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="*">
    <xsl:choose>

      <!-- call template without param -->
      <xsl:when test="name() = 'xs:complexType'">
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        <xsl:text> contains </xsl:text>

        <xsl:call-template name="top"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>

      <!-- for contained elements with types -->
      <xsl:when test="@type != ''  and  name() = 'xs:element' and $typeToLocate = ''">
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        <xsl:text> of type </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@type"/>
        <xsl:text>(which contains: </xsl:text>

        <!--
          point at which i want processor to return to root, locate the
          indicated complex type, output its contents then continue going
          through schema.
        -->
        <xsl:call-template name="top">
          <xsl:with-param name="typeToLocate" select="@type"/>
        </xsl:call-template>

        <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>

      <!-- when type is located, send it to signal proper output -->
      <xsl:when test="$typeToLocate != ''  and  $typeToLocate = @name">
        <xsl:call-template name="top">
          <xsl:with-param name="typeToLocate" select="$typeToLocate"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>

      <!-- for elements contained in indicated type -->
      <xsl:when test="$typeToLocate != ''  and  name() = 'xs:element'">
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>

        <xsl:call-template name="top">
          <xsl:with-param name="typeToLocate" select="$typeToLocate"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>

      <!-- for continuing through non-content elements under found type -->
      <xsl:when test="$typeToLocate != ''">
        <xsl:call-template name="top">
          <xsl:with-param name="typeToLocate" select="$typeToLocate"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>

      <!-- for ignoring non-content elements during normal processing -->
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:call-template name="top"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>

    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: To amplify Garrison's response, short of writing the code for you (which I don't do, this is not a free programming service) it's hard to answer the question without knowing where you got stuck. Showing us your best attempt at a solution would reveal what you know and what you don't know, which would help us to produce an answer that helps you.

Comment: Sorry, added an edit of a mellowed out portion of what I've written(would have attached it sooner but it wasn't too readable).  Hopefully it conveys what I'm looking for.

Comment: Just curious, is this for some sort of assignment that would measure XSLT/XSD skills? Or a fun project for one particular XSD? The reason I am asking... what if you're using XML namespaces? Are you going to expand prefixes into URIs? What if an XSD references other XSDs (include/import/redefine)? For fun, try to code for some circular dependencies: types, groups, or XSD files... What I mean, if you're in for real life XSDs, you might want to reconsider the use of XSLT for this particular task.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question broadly, without giving a specific style-sheet, I would suggest ...

(1) Create a template to match complex types at the XSD public level. The sequence constructor for the said template will be directly responsible for the production of text like "S ".

(2) Within the said sequence constructor, but after the said text production, invoke  on the complex type node. This will be responsible for the remainder of the desired production, starting from "contains ...".

(3) Create the describe-contents template. The sequence contructor here will consist of two parts:
  (3.1) A constant production like "contains ";
  (3.2) a call to apply-templates for the sequence members. This part is going to produce like "A of type X(which ~)"

(4) Create a template to match xs:sequence/xs:element. As you will guess from 3.2, the sequence constructor will have 3 parts:
  (4.1) A production like "A of type X(which "
  (4.2) A call to the describe-contents template in relation to the child complex type); and finally
  (4.3) A constant production of ")"

That should do it if your goals are limited to xs:sequence and complex types. Never-the-less, this template based approach, where the templates roughly match up to the syntactic elements, should be extensible to xs:choice etc.

I have assumed that you actually want a recursive description for deep level complex type definitions.